# How do I find out my password?

Tags: window

I tried all the things I found on here and nothing worked, is it because I have windows 7 on my PC too?

Comment: If you have forgotten your password in ubuntu, why don't you reset ?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to find out you password as it is a hashed form of it.

If you really want to it would take stupid amounts of cpu and time.

Comment: you can still reset is as mentioned above